# What do double curly brackets mean in struct declaration?

Tags: go

Can someone please explain me what do double curly brackets `{{` mean in this code ?  :

```
func (t *testService) APIs() []rpc.API {
    return []rpc.API{{
        Namespace: "test",
        Version:   "1.0",
        Service: &TestAPI{
            state:     &t.state,
            peerCount: &t.peerCount,
        },
    }}
}
```

AFIK single curly bracket is enough to create a struct, so why to double it?

the API struct is defined like this:

```
package rpc

// API describes the set of methods offered over the RPC interface
type API struct {
    Namespace string      // namespace under which the rpc methods of Service are exposed
    Version   string      // api version for DApp's
    Service   interface{} // receiver instance which holds the methods
    Public    bool        // indication if the methods must be considered safe for public use
}
```

Comment: You're not just creating a struct, you have a composite literal of a slice _containing_ a struct.

Comment: @JimB ok, but I am still not getting it, according to your logic, what object the first `{` create and what object does the second `{` create?

Comment: The first one is the slice, the second the structure. If you had 2 element on the slice, you would have something like this; {{...},{...}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a slightly shorter version of this (fewer lines and less indenting):

```
return []rpc.API{
    {
        Namespace: "test",
        Version:   "1.0",
        Service: &TestAPI{
            state:     &t.state,
            peerCount: &t.peerCount,
        },
    },
}
```

It's a slice of structs with one element in it.

Answer (score 2):

`[]rpc.API{ }` defines an empty slice of `rpc.API`'s.  You can put any number of `rpc.API`'s inside those curly brackets to make them elements of the slice.

The code you have is the same as:

```
a := rpc.API{ Namespace: "test", ... }
return []rpc.API{ a }
```